# Conditionally create one array from two other arrays in VB?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I have two arrays

```
a={a,b,c,d}
b={1,2,3,4}
```

now I want to create a 3rd array which should at least contains one numeric number and rest of alphabets, this code will generate unique usernames so it should not repeat the pattern of selection which is present in main array

```
Darray={abc1, acd2,...}
```

I united `a` and `b`

```
Dim c As String() = Barray.Union(Aarray).ToArray()

        Dim Carray(0 To 8) As String
```

I am thinking about having a do while loop here but don't know how can I pass this conditions that it should get at least one number and should not repeat the pattern from `Darray`

```
do while (confused....)
        Dim rnd As New Random

        For i = 0 To 8

            Carray(i) = c(rnd.Next(0, c.Length))

        Next
loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a form, and paste this cod. It generates 100 codes, perhaps it is what you want? Add a listbox on the form and uncomment the ADD line to see the results.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim aa() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
    Dim an() As String = {"1", "2", "3", "4"}
    Dim da As New Collection
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < 100
        Dim j1 As Integer = rnd.Next(4)
        Dim j2 As Integer = rnd.Next(4)
        Dim rs As String = ""
        For k As Integer = 1 To 4
            If k = j2 Then
                rs += an(j1)
            Else
                Dim j3 As Integer = rnd.Next(4)
                rs += aa(j3)
            End If
        Next
        If Not da.Contains(rs) Then
            da.Add(rs, rs)
            ' ListBox1.Items.Add(rs)
            i += 1
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: hi martin, thanks for answer it works but could you explain me something here , if i dont want it to repeat same character from aa then how to pass that condition, its not necessary but its a complex method so in future it might help

Answer (score 0):

Update for USER1167053, answering "`if i dont want it to repeat`":

replace the FOR looop with:

```
        Dim k As Integer = 0
        While k < 4
            If k = j2 Then
                rs += an(j1)
                k += 1
            Else
                Dim j3 As Integer = rnd.Next(4)
                If Not rs.Contains(aa(j3)) Then
                    rs += aa(j3)
                    k += 1
                End If
            End If
        End While
```

Take care that the number of solutions is greater then the limit you impose, otherwise the program goes in infinite loop